# Support RSA encryption on Android, iOS and Java (SPRING) server

Tags: java, android, ios, cross-platform, rsa

We have a system which includes Android and iPhone apps as well as a backend server. The applications can send certain sensitive information to one another. In order to do so they generate a keypair when logging in and send the public key to the server. The server then uses that public key to encrypt the sensitive data and only the receiving app can decrypt it using its private key. We currently have it up and running for Android but are facing issues for iPhone. I have looked all over and seen some suggestions but cannot seem to fix it.

The public key is sent to and stored on the server as a base64 encoded string and used serverside by

```
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedPublicKey);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
return cipher.doFinal(rawStringToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

This works for both iOS and Android. When generating the public key on iOS we needed to add the ASN1 headers etc manually before sending it to the server. But the server now accepts the keys sent from iOS and uses them for encrypting (everything looks OK there). 
When an Android app receives encrypted data it simply does

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedPrivateKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt), "UTF-8");
return decryptedString;
```

where it creates its private key from a stored base64 string that it got when generating its key pair. For iOS however, we have tried a large number of different solutions but are never able to decrypt data that the server encrypts with our public key. We generate the KeyPair, manipulate the public key so we can send it to the server and then store our private key. We get the SecKeyRef from our keychain (also has tried to store it as bytes and create it from bytes) and perform `SecKeyDecrypt` with that key and have tested both `kSecPaddingPKCS1` as well as `kSecPaddingNone`.

Does anyone have a working solution for decrypting data that a Java server encrypt the way I have described?

Comment: How are you creating the key on iOS? How are you exporting the key on iOS? What is the size of your RSA key? How long can `rawStringToEncrypt` be? If the plaintext does not fit in a single RSA block, how is that handled? I see you use: `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` for encrypting...is this actually using ECB if the plaintext is larger? Are you using Bouncy Castle on the Java side? Generally you use RSA to protect (ie encrypt) a randomly generated AES key which encrypts the plaintext. You then send the AES encrypted text + the RSA encrypted AES key?

Comment: Wouldn't that generally only be used if the key pair is used to set up some kind of session? In this case the server keeps your public key and encrypts small strings very rarely. We never "send much data" between to devices with the data encrypted (of course we use https for that). So in our case I don't see any upside with generating an AES key and encrypt that instead of the plaintext.

Comment: Regarding the rest: We somehow read out the public key from the iOS keychain the wrong way. When we instead used the bytes from SecKeyRefExternalRepresentation then we had the correct bytes to which we added the needed headers. So we now have PKCS1 padding on all sides working.

Comment: Hybrid encryption is most commonly used and doesn't require a session. While TLS does Diffie Hellman key exchange, other protocols like PGP, s/mime use RSA just for key encryption and rely on a randomly generated symmetric key.  2048 RSA can encrypt 245 bytes. If you try to split the data larger than this and encrypt each block separately, there are a number of security pitfalls beyond the obvious performance overhead.

Comment: You can totally use RSA to encrypt messages, I just needed the info to be able to adequately answer your question since trying to encrypt more than 245 bytes could have very well been the issue